# Conditional Table change in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I tried to work out around this. But I think I am getting no where.

I have 3 tables:

This tale contains all questions and question types:

```
    Table: Ref
    id    |    type   |   info
    ==========================
    1          SS         Education
    ---------------------------
    2          RB         Gender
    ---------------------------
    3          ST         State
```

This table contains "options" for the questions in the above table 'Ref`

```
    Table: ref_ans
    id    |  q_id   |   answer_text
    ===========================
    1          1        Masters     
    ---------------------------
    2          1        Bachelors     
    ---------------------------
    3          1        Undergrad
    ---------------------------
    4          2        Male     
    ---------------------------
    5          2        Female
    ---------------------------
    6          2        Dont want to disclose
```

This table contains states (`type` ="ST" in table `Ref`)

```
    Table: us_states

    id    |  answer_text 
    ===========================
    1        Alaska     
    ---------------------------
    2        Alabama     
    ---------------------------
    3        Arkansan
    ---------------------------
    4        Arizona     
    ---------------------------
    5        Baltimore
    ---------------------------
    etc
```

The result I want is:

```
    ref.id, ref_ans.id, ref.answer_text / us_states.answer_text
```

**for a given `ref.question_id` **.

And the condition is: If the question_id, for which the answers requested is 'ST', it should pull the answers from `us_states`, otherwise, it should pull from `ref-ans` table.

I tried this. Obviously, this did not work:

```
    SELECT ref.id, 
         CASE WHEN ref.type = 'ST' THEN 
             (SELECT ID, answer_text FROM us_states )
         ELSE 
             (SELECT id, answer_text FROM ref_ans)  
    END

    FROM ref
   WHERE ref.ID = <id>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how is `us_states.id` related to the other tables? i mean, is `us_states.id` the same as `Ref.id` ?

Comment: No. There is no reference to ref.id in us_states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT    a.id, 
          COALESCE(b.id, c.id) AS ans_id,
          COALESCE(b.answer_text, c.answer_text) AS answer_text
FROM      ref a
LEFT JOIN ref_ans b ON a.id = b.q_id
LEFT JOIN us_states c ON a.type = 'ST'
WHERE     a.id = <id> AND (
              (a.type <> 'ST' AND b.id IS NOT NULL) OR
              (a.type =  'ST' AND c.id IS NOT NULL)
          )
```

Comment: I have to give you +100 :-). There was a small glitch. It shows a record with null values even if there are no records on B for the specific question ID. So I added "is not null" on first join and it all works now. Thanks much!

Comment: @KevinRave, I'm concerned about your edit. You ***NEED*** the first join to be `NULL` in the event that the question is a `ST` question so that COALESCE can use the `NULL` value to skip over to the answers in the `us_states` table. What I think you want to filter out is questions that don't have any answers at all. I will revise my solution to account for that.

Comment: Yes, I just do not want null for the non existing answers. But not sure, when I tried with NOT NULL in the join, it appears to work. However, I will try your edit.

Comment: @KevinRave, see my edit. The additions to the `WHERE` clause ensure that you only get questions that have either regular answer choices or state answer choices.

Comment: I think it fails now. Nothing is returning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the three tables are connected by id(1st column):

```
  SELECT ref_ans.id, ref.id, if(ref.type='ST', us_states.answer_text, ref_ans.answer_text) as answer_text
    FROM ref_ans  
    JOIN ref  on ref.id=ref_ans.id
    JOIN us_states on ref.id=us_states.id
    WHERE ref_ans.q_id = <id>
```